# Ubuntu login loop, but have another user account

Tags: boot, permissions, login, sudo, password

I cannot login to my main user account. I have entered the password right. When I enter the password correctly, the ubuntu login window freezes for around 3 seconds and then just returns to the login screen. When I enter a password incorrectly, it instantly tells me the password is incorrect.

When I try pressing CTRL + ALT + 1,2,3, and log in, it will successfully login, but not allow me to enter commands and then will timeout at about 15 seconds and log me back out.

I went into recovery mode and I was able to log into my main user account there. While I was in there I created a new user. I logged into the new user successfully while out of recovery mode. I went back into recovery mode and added it to the sudoers list sudo adduser  sudo.

**TL;DR for above, CTRL + ALT 2 does not work, created a new accout with sudo privs via recovery options**

Now that I can login with my new test user account and it is added to the sudoers list... I don't really know what else to now. I really want to be able to login to my main account, unless there is a very good way to ensure that I recopy 100% of my files on user account to the new user account.

**NOTE: I leave my PC on at night (with sleep mode turned off) and I found it frozen, so I restarted it and then this happened**

**Note: not using nvida, using AMD gpu**

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with your user profile, did you change your ~/.profile or similar?

Comment: Nope, I leave my PC on and I found it frozen, so I restarted it and then this happened (Also I don't use sleep, so my ubuntu is awake all night) @Esther

Comment: so it sounds like something got corrupted when you force-shutdown, I guess. Not sure what it could be, maybe someone else will know what info is needed. But that is important info to add to your question, you can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438437/edit) it to add the info.

Comment: @Nmath I moved my .config file to another directory, and the problem still happens, but I also moved some other .bash_ files and then tested it again and it seems to be working. will update after done troubleshooting and getting the exact cause, hopefully the line number(s) and the relative content of the line number in one of these files

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how this happened... but I was importing/including .bash_profile inside of .bash_profile. I commented it out and it is working now. Like I said, I leave my PC on at night so this might have been in there for awhile 4-7 days and then I had a crash last night and I just noticed it.

[recursion import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3B1K.jpg)